# pyspark unix_timestamp sometime return null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

for certain strings - unix_timestamp return null

```
raw_data.select(F.unix_timestamp(F.lit("2019-03-10T02:56:36Z"),format=date_format)).show(1)
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|unix_timestamp(2019-03-10T02:56:36Z, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z')|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                          null|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

but for almost the same string - i do get the answer:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|unix_timestamp(to_utc_timestamp(2019-03-10T02:56:36Z, America/New_York), yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                   1552204596|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

when i first convert the problematic string to UTC timestamp - it works....

```
raw_data.select(F.unix_timestamp(F.to_utc_timestamp(F.lit("2019-03-10T02:56:36Z"), "America/New_York"))).show(1)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|unix_timestamp(to_utc_timestamp(2019-03-10T02:56:36Z, America/New_York), yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                   1552204596|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

is it a problem in converting string with unix_timestamp ? 
how can i avoid converting to UTC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the timestamp `2019-03-10T02:56:36Z` as **daylight** saving time starts on march 10 at 2AM.

- On daylight savings time clock will be set to `3AM` skipping `2AM` entirely, So there is no **`02:56`** time recorded and that's the **reason** for resulting `null`.
- When to use `to_utc_timestamp` you are converting timestamp to UTC i.e `+5:00` and then time becomes `07:56` which is valid results unix_time without `null`.
- To Fix the issue use `regexp_replace` inside `unix_timestamp` to replace **`2019-03-10T02`** to **`2019-03-10T03`**.

**`Example:`**

```
#invalid time
spark.sql("""select unix_timestamp('2019-03-10T02:56:36Z', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") unix_time""").show()
#+---------+
#|unix_time|
#+---------+
#|     null|
#+---------+

#valid time
spark.sql("""select unix_timestamp('2019-03-10T03:56:36Z', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") unix_time""").show()
#+----------+
#| unix_time|
#+----------+
#|1552208196|
#+----------+

#to fix the issue use regexp replace to replace 2019-03-10T02 to 2019-03-10T03
spark.sql("""select unix_timestamp(regexp_replace('2019-03-10T02:56:36Z','2019-03-10T02','2019-03-10T03'), "yyyy-MM-
+----------+
| unix_time|
+----------+
|1552208196|
+----------+
```

Comment: wouldn't setting the sessions TZ to UTC solve the problem ?
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")

Comment: @user1450410, You can try that option too, but make sure you are not getting nulls while converting back to `unix_timestamp` and getting correct unix_timestamp values after changing the session timezone to `UTC`!

Comment: yes, i am not interested in the value itself in my TZ , just doing data diff in seconds between 2 dates , so the one liner of setting the TZ to UTC solves it !